# How to define and use a tag system for my TODO app in room database

Tags: android, android-room

I've got a simple TODO app, each TODO is stored in the room datase. But I want to add tags for these TODO's so that each TODO could have 0 or more tags and each tag is a siple string. So the question is: what is the best solution for this situation? How to store this set of tags for each TODO?

Comment: you can store multiple tags using string and make it separated by comma. Use chip for the showing same tags in your TODO details-https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a many-many relationship. This entails using a third table in addition to the TAG table and the TODO table. Such a table has two columns one that references the TAG table, the other that references the TODO table.

The PRIMARY KEY, should be a composite PRIMARY KEY made up of both columns (so a TODO/TAG combination must be unique i.e. you don't want a TODO to have the same tag twice).

This answer covers this in SQLite terms [What is the best way to design a tag-based data table with Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128832/what-is-the-best-way-to-design-a-tag-based-data-table-with-sqlite/51129237#51129237)

This answer covers this from a Room perspective
[Relationship many to many between objects not working for me in Android Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604675/relationship-many-to-many-between-objects-not-working-for-me-in-android-room/71610656#71610656)